# Parasoft REST Client

Tags: parasoft

I'm newbie to webservice automation. Today I was creating the **RESTFUL** services, there I found different options in the **Method dropdown field**. I'm wondering what will be the usage for those. And I went through the help options in Parasoft tool. But I don't find any explanation regarding the same.

I would like to know the difference between each of them? And when to use when?

POST
GET
OPTIONS
HEAD
PUT
DELETE
TRACE
CUSTOM

I'm using Parasoft SOA Test Version 9.8
Could anyone help me out? 
And herewith attached the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to invoke a REST service, you have to use one of those HTTP Methods along with the URL of the service. This is the basis of REST services and is the same for any form of REST invocation : via SOATest, CURL, Postman, etc.

I think you need to first learn about REST services. This might be a good place to start : http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html

For reference on usage of different HTTP Methods, refer : http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

On a side note, Parasoft does not list PATCH method in the drop down list. If you need you will have to Select Custom and Type PATCH in the text box.